# Replacing newline doesn't work

Tags: python, string, replace

I have a `.txt` file form which I read multiple lines and append an array with every line.
Unfortunately I also have the line breaks in the array.

When I try to replace them with `line.replace("\n", "")`, nothing will happen.

Comment: `line.strip()` will cut the spaces

Comment: if there is `\n` at end of each line try `line.strip('\n')`

Comment: It's not about spaces, but about the \n part.
.strip didn't work either.

Comment: My thought is, that python does \n not see as a part of the string, but as a command. Maybe its something like that?

Comment: After you read the files and uploaded the array, can you go through the array and delete every "\n"? You could use that replace method which have suggested by others

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you just doing `line.replace("\n", "")`? If so, that's the problem. You are doing the replacement, then throwing away the result.  You need:

```
line = line.replace("\n", "")
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but even saving the result in another variable. I started breaking it in code units to find the problem and I found that my input had carriage returns, which is '\r'. They made visually the same result as the '\n' in the output file. So I fixed it by doing the following:

```
result = input.replace("\n", "").replace("\r", "");
```